# Bash Script Get Port Usage

Tags: bash

I need to find out if a port is in use in a specific port range.

I am setting up a script to create php-fpm pools, and want to make sure I can check for the next available port that is not in use.

```
netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-11211} -q ;
```

Gets me what I need for seeing if that specific port is in use, but how can I do this for a port range?  Say... 11211 - 12655

Should I loop a range, and stop at the "found" next available?
However, this is returning me 1's for everything.

```
for i in {11212..12655}
do
    netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-i} -q ;
    echo $i:$?
done

    i=11212;
END=12655;
while [ $i -le $END ]; do
    netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-i} -q ;
    echo $?;
    i=$(($i+1));
done;
```

Comment: you are checking the 4th column of `netstat`, right?

Comment: Generally speaking, this approach is race-prone; it's better to have your application actually try and go on to the next port when it fails than to do an up-front test (since the set of allocated ports can change between when you run that test and when you actually try to bind your socket). You might combine the approaches, but still should fall back to increment-and-retry.

Comment: Sorry @CharlesDuffy but I'm not exactly sure what that means.   technically all I want to do is find the next available port in that range.  I figured a loop, and once a 1 is presented, exit the loop and store the port it found.   This will only be used by one person at a time, so I am not concerned at all about multiple instances of it running....

Comment: BINGO!   changing `${1:-i}` to `${1:-$i}` is now getting me the 0's I expected to see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in {11212..12655}
do
    netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-i} -q ;
    echo $i:$?
done
```

Does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare numbers, `grep` will make you use regular expressions. And a regex for a range 11211-12655 is going to be a bit boring to type.

What about using `awk` instead?

```
netstat -ntpl | awk 'split($4, a, ":")==2 && a[2]>=11211 && a[2]<=12655'
```

This gets the 4th column of `netstat`'s output and splits its content in two `:`-separated slices. Then, you have the data in the array `a[]` to play with and define the range you want it to match.

Comment: sort of what I am looking for, but this is what that gets me: http://prntscr.com/cippsr

Comment: @Kevin well you are mixing concepts: `a[1]` is a variable in `awk`. When you `echo $A[0]` you are printing a variable in bash that does not have anything to do with awk. Please update your question showing what is your desired outpupt, because maybe something as simple as `netstat -ntpl | awk 'split($4, a, ":")==2 && a[2]>=11211 && a[2]<=12655 {print a[1]}` will do.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines:

 i=11212
 END=12655
 while [ $i -le $END ]; do
  netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-i} -q ;
  echo $?;
  i=$(($i+1))
 done
 
But... the output lists almost everything in bin lol

Comment: In your comment with a link you are missing the final single quote after `{print a[1]}`. `awk` commands consist in `awk '...'`. And I see it comes from me missing it in my previous comment.